# Unmarshalling SOAP with JAXB leaves ANY-element empty (null)

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, jaxb

I'm unmarshalling a SOAP-message with JAXB, and while most of the message looks fine when unmarshalled, one element is null when its content should be plain text. If I change its content to xml (e.g. `<Test> Something </test>`, it works fine.

I beleive the schema describing this part is the following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="NotificationMessageHolderType" >
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="Topic" 
                            type="wsnt:TopicExpressionType" 
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
               <xsd:element name="ProducerReference" 
                            type="wsa:EndpointReferenceType" 
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
               <xsd:element name="Message" type="xsd:anyType" 
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
```

The problem is with the LAST element in this schema, the **Message** element. Its type is "xsd:anyType", doesn't that mean it could hold anything? But when unmarshalling with JAXB, any non-structured content (verbatim text) seems to get omitted.

Does anybody know why, and what I might do to remedy the situation?

Regards, 
Eflite

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004075851/http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_16_1-Elements-With-Any-Type.html)(note, wayback machine archived item) is the best place to look for the answer; it provides a clear example on how to address your scenario.

I am quoting from there:
*"If you need to marshal arbitrary content you'll have to create a content tree according to org.w3c.dom. Sun's JAXB currently uses the implementation from Apache's Xerces, i.e., class apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl."*